# How to change the String containing zero and one to boolean function in Java?

Tags: java, function, boolean

I have a string that is a boolean function. I want to calculate its value in boolean.
Is there any function to do that in Java?

I have string line `str = "0+1+!(0+1+1)+1*0+!1";`

**I want this:** boolean `result =  false || true || !(false || true || true) || true && false || !true;`

I did it for the strings whose length is 4 elements by using conditions but I have to apply this to a String that consists of more than 20 elements.

It is impossible to calculate all of the combinations.
What do you think I should do?

Comment: `Is there any function to do that in Java?` No.  I think some JavaScript engines (which certain version of Java do come bundled with) could do something like this natively, but with just Java you'll have to write your own parser/interpreter.

Comment: You will have to parse the string and translate it to what you want.

Comment: What you are actually asking for is an interpreter for an expression language. There are plenty available in java. You probably need to apply some transformations to your string to create the right format for the expression language of your choice. Some expression languages for java are listed here: https://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages

Comment: Check out [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20shunting,abstract%20syntax%20tree%20(AST)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ScriptEngine:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {

        ScriptEngineManager manager=new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine=manager.getEngineByName("js");

        String in="0+1+!(0+1+1)+1*0+!1";
        in=in.replaceAll("0", "false");
        in=in.replaceAll("1", "true");
        in=in.replaceAll("\\+", "||");
        in=in.replaceAll("\\*", "&&");
        //System.out.println(in);

        Boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(engine.eval(in).toString());
        System.out.println(result);
    
    }
}
```

**Update.** Previous code works for Java versions from 8 to 14. For new versions you can add next dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
    <version>22.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
    <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    <version>22.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and change code:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager=new ScriptEngineManager();  
    ScriptEngine engine=manager.getEngineByName("graal.js");
```

Comment: Doesn't work as written.  Returned engine is `null`.

Comment: Probably you use Java 15+. I updated answer.